# Building a list using LINQ from two lists

Tags: linq, list

I have two lists:

List1 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K' }

List2 = { 'B', 'C', 'D' }

List1 is all the columns in a table and List2 are the columns that make up a foreign or primary key on that same table.

In this example, 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D' are a primary key of a table. 'B', 'C' and 'D' are a foreign key of the same table. 'G' and 'H' are two columns of a table I don't want to include.

I can't seem to be able to write a LINQ statement that produces this:

List3 = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'K' }

List3 is a list of the parameters I want to give to an "UPDATE" stored procedure I am generating. List2 + 'K' will be my "WHERE"; 'E', 'F', 'I' and 'J' will be the columns the procedure will use in the "SET".

Both List1 and List2 will be different every time the LINQ is executed.

All lists are of type List where DbColumn is defined as:

```
public class DbColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    //public bool IsForeignKey { get; set; }
    public int OrdinalPosition { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public int CharMaxLength { get; set; }
    public bool AllowNulls { get; set; }

    public static DbColumn Create(string name, int ordinal_position, string data_type, int charMaxLength, string is_nullable)
    {
        DbColumn column = new DbColumn();

        column.Name = name;
        //column.IsPrimaryKey = isPk;
        //column.IsForeignKey = isFk;
        column.OrdinalPosition = ordinal_position;
        column.DataType = data_type;
        column.CharMaxLength = charMaxLength;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(is_nullable))
            column.AllowNulls = is_nullable.ToUpper() == "YES" ? true : false;
        else
            column.AllowNulls = false;

        return column;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Columns can be part of DbConstraint and DbTable. DbTable also has DbConstraint as a properties:

```
public class DbTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catalog { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public List<DbColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    public DbSProc Insert { get; set; }
    public DbSProc Update { get; set; }
    public DbSProc Delete { get; set; }
    public List<DbSProc> ReadProcedures { get; set; }
    public List<DbConstraint> Constraints { get; set; }

    public static DbTable Create(string name, string catalog, string schema, List<DbColumn> columns)
    {
        DbTable table = new DbTable();

        table.Catalog = catalog;
        table.Schema = schema;
        table.Name = name;
        table.Columns = columns;
        table.ReadProcedures = new List<DbSProc>();

        return table;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class DbConstraint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public List<DbColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    public static DbConstraint Create(string name, bool isPrimary)
    {
        DbConstraint constraint = new DbConstraint();
        constraint.Name = name;
        constraint.IsPrimary = isPrimary;
        constraint.Columns = new List<DbColumn>();

        return constraint;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

The goal of the LINQ statement is to select for parameters only those columns that are necessary for the "WHERE" piece (e.g.: a foreign/primary key plus "_VerCol") and those necessary for the "SET" piece (non-primary keys).

You can find the code on CodePlex: https://sqlmeth.codeplex.com.

Can anybody help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not explaining the logic which goes from List1 and List2 to List3. Do you take entries from List1 once the first entry in List2 occurs? Do you take all entries in List1 greater than the smallest in List2?

Comment: I appreciate you updating your question, but you really need to explain it even better. You appear to be dealing with more than just three lists. Can you explicitly describe what `List1` and `List2` are? And how do we know that `G` and `H` are special? And how do we know that `A` is special and `E`, `F`, `I`, `J`, and `K` are not?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thank you. I didn't really want to get into much detail because I thought people will get confused and the question might get lost in the dialogue.

I have the project in CodePlex, it's called SqlMeth: https://sqlmeth.codeplex.com. The procedure's name is "GenerateSpecificUpdateSprocs" in Hallucinator.cs. The issue is generating the enumerable "parameter".

I will add more info on the question.

Comment: @Jaquio - People were confused with lack of detail. And, even though you have now added the classes, you still haven't **explicitly** defined what `List1` and `List2` are. I understand that they're both `List<DbColumn>`, but you haven't explained how they relate to each other and how we can determine which columns to keep and which to discard **based** on the values from `List1` and `List2`. The most important part of asking a question here is to spend the time writing a good question to make answering as easy as possible. You haven't done that.

Comment: Writing the goal of what I wanted to do helped me see the solution to my question. I modified my code to exclude the primary keys from the table columns (List1) and then only add the keys needed on the stored procedure (List2). This made me notice another issue: "Contains" was not evaluating properly the objects. After overriding "Equals" everything seems to be working fine. @Enigmativity - I'll work on writing better questions for next time ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you know the characters you want to exclude.

```
List<char> a = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K' };
List<char> b = new List<char>() { 'B', 'C', 'D' };
List<char> exclusionList = new List<char> {'A','G', 'H'};

List<char> c = a.Select(x => x).Where(x => !exclusionList.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it help me to some extent. In my case, overriding "Equals" was also necessary.